# AWS .Net Core Serverless Application - where is the 'profile' information stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have created a simple .Net Core Serverless App for AWS Lambda. When I publish to AWS from Visual Studio, everything makes sense - the profile is set with the IAM Key, and everything is good.

But I decided to implement CI/CD with Bitbucket, and I am not sure how the publish to AWS is still working ? Where does it store the profile information ? How does the deploy-serverless command know which profile to use...

Here is the yml file for context:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        deployment: test
        script: # Modify the comma`nds below to build your repository.
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y
          - apt-get install --reinstall zip -y
          - cd MyApplication
          - dotnet build
          - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
          - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
          - dotnet-lambda deploy-serverless
```

Comment: By "Profile" you mean credential or the lambda function configuration?

Comment: 'Profile' as in the credentials for the IAM user. You set this profile up when publishing the App from Visual Studio to AWS serverless, by grtting the credentials .CSV of an IAM user from AWS, and attaching it to a profile.